# Explanation of an equation in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, covariance

$$
{\partial (0.5 (\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu})^2) \over \partial(\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu})} = {(\partial_{\rho} A^{\rho}) g^{\mu \nu} }
$$
Can somebody explain why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is written a little loosely as $\mu$ is a dummy index in the numerator and a free index in the denominator.  I'm going to change the dummy index for clarity.  Also since you tagged special relativity instead of general relativity, I'm assuming that $g_{\mu\nu}$ is actually Minkowski, which seems to be necessary for the answer you got.

Define $B_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}$. Then you have
$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial B_{\mu\nu}} (B_{\rho}^{\ \ \rho})^2 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial B_{\mu\nu}} (g^{\rho\alpha} B_{\rho\alpha})^2$$

From there you can use regular calculus, noting that $\partial B_{\alpha\beta} / \partial B_{\gamma\rho} = \delta_{\alpha\gamma} \delta_{\beta\rho}$.

Comment: The metric doesn't depend on $B_{\mu\nu}$, so it should come out of the derivative.  Use the power rule to take care of the exponent and then you should have a derivative for which you can pull out the remaining factor of the metric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule